# Get Python values from C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, variables, file-io

I have the next code on Python:

test.py

```
def func(text, number):
    a = text
    b = number
```

And the next code in C++

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(void)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* main_module =
       PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject* main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);

    FILE* file = fopen("test.py", "r");
    PyRun_File(file, "test.py",
               Py_file_input,
               main_dict, main_dict);
    return 0;
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Now, what i want to do, is get the values from Python to use them in C.
I mean, take the "a" value, and the "b" value.

Am i running the Python code in the correct way to get this?

Should i use global variables?

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, but are you sure  `Py_Finalize()` gets called?

Comment: You are right! I'm using return 0 befor Py_Finalize(). Btw, it works without any problem xD

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a sensible thing to do. Those are local variables in a function that doesn't return anything and is never called.

Probably it would make the most sense to return the values from the function, and then call the function from C/C++.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, how can i do that?

Comment: @Mrat , you could return them from python as a tuple:  `return (a,b)` and get the return value from the function in the C++ code

Comment: @Alejandro , sorry, but this is my first day with Python from C. How can i get the tuple?